# Pivot Table Filtering Office Scripts

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have an excel Pivot Table titled PivotTable1. Utilizing Office Scripts I am trying to automate the filtering. There are two columns prescriber and spent amount. I am trying to add a filter to the sum of the spent amount when it’s greater than $325. Essentially trying to automate the filter value function in excel.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8eAm.png)

Comment: I'm curious about how this script/automation fits into your workflow. Is this something you run on a schedule or is it triggered by some event?

Comment: Thank you for your help on this!  We get a weekly spreadsheet from our Finance team with updated expenses that we have in a SharePoint file.  The flow runs on a weekly schedule and this script is to create a new pivot table to aggregate total expenses by person and then filter for anything greater than $325.  The flow then sends out email notifications to everyone who is over the spending limit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the below Office Script should be similar to what you are trying to do. The [Office Script Pivot Table interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.pivottable?view=office-scripts) is in documentation but there aren't a lot of great samples matching your goals, at least they aren't readily available. I poked around in the forum and swear I saw a previous post with similar question but lost that tab.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  // declare the target pivot table
  let moviesPivot = workbook.getPivotTable("PivotTable4");

  // declare the field you are filtering
  let filterField = moviesPivot.getHierarchy("Title");

  // declare the filter to only include rows with budget over...
  let filter: ExcelScript.PivotValueFilter = {
    condition: ExcelScript.ValueFilterCondition.greaterThan,
    comparator: 2000000,
    value: "Sum of budget"
  };

  // apply the value filter to the field
  filterField.getPivotField("Title").applyFilter({ valueFilter: filter });

}
```